# What does this regex does?

Tags: regex

This is the string from Automapping configuration of NHibernate. I wonder what it does.

```
return string.Format("{0}_", Regex.Replace(member.Name, "([a-z](?=[A-Z])|[A-Z](?=[A-Z][a-z]))", "$1_").ToUpper());
```

Answer (score 7):

Ok, let's break it up.

```
//This is the start
([a-z](?=[A-Z])|[A-Z](?=[A-Z][a-z]))

[a-z](?=[A-Z]) //this means to match one lower case a-z followed by an uppercase A-Z
| //or
[A-Z](?=[A-Z][a-z]) //One uppercase A-Z followed by one uppercase and one lowercase a-z

//The replace
$1_ //Replace the match with "the match plus underscore". 
//aBxx would become a_Bxx and ABcxx would be A_Bcxx
```

[image]

Comment: What program did you use to generate that diagram?

Comment: It's a great tool to learn/visualize regexp's: [Regexper.com](http://www.regexper.com)

Comment: I would note that the lookaheads mean those characters won't be replaced by the replacement although they have to match for the regex to match.

Comment: Interesting that one answer "breaks it up" and the other "breaks it down" :)

Comment: @ivarni Hah, I saw that too. I'm not a native english writer so I could've gotten it wrong :)

Answer (score 0):

Lets break it down:

```
([a-z](?=[A-Z])
```

The first section matches any lower case character that ends in an upper case character

```
|[A-Z](?=[A-Z][a-z]))
```

Or any upper case character that ends in an upper then a lower case character

For example this will match

AAb with the first 'A' being the match or

aB

with the 'a' being the match.

The regex is using http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html